# Regex: match '/.' only if not prefixed with '/_local/.'

Tags: regex, nginx, couchdb

I hate regex! My brain just does not work the way regex does. Can someone please help with the following problem I'm trying to solve ?

I have a nginx config file currently blocking all attempts to access system or hidden files for security reasons (i.e. files beginning with '.') with the below *location config*:

```
location ~ \/\. {
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  deny all;
}
```

However, this also blocks my CouchDB server requests to `example.com/db/_local/.XYZ`

I want to allow all requests to `X/_local/.X` but deny all other requests to `X/.X`.

So my regex has to match all `/.` but not `/_local/.`.

Eg

```
example.com/.secretfile          // deny
example.com/db/_local/.LONGHASH  // allow
example.com/other/.other         // deny
```

Can anyone RegEx gurus please help out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed that Ngninx is fully PCRE-compatible, this should be a solution:

```
location ~ (?<!\/_local)\/\. {
```

This uses a “negative look-behind assertion”: `(?<!\/_local)` means “not prefixed by `/_local`”.

**Edit:** Escaped forward slashes

Comment: Awesome work you champion! I had to make a slight modification to escape the forward slashes for it to work. Updated your answer with working solution. Thanks again!